# Delphi IDE hangs while debugging threads

Tags: multithreading, delphi, debugging

This is kind of a follow-up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436524/keep-app-responsive-during-long-task). When I'm debugging threads in Delphi (BDS 2006 with update 2) my IDE often hangs, e.g. when the execution runs into a breakpoint that I have set **after** the app started.

Do you have similar experiences? What do you do about it?

Comment: I did not see that yet, what Delphi version?

Comment: Please see edit in main post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There have been reports of this with pre-D2009 versions = I remember BCB2006 suffering from this.

The workaround - IIRC - is to remove the "Local Variables" debug window.

> Report No: 30653 (RAID: 239655)
> Status: Closed Debugger causes IDE to
> lockup
>
> http://qc.codegear.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=30653
>
> qcwin:DEFECT_NO=30653

Comment: Sounds somewhat familiar even if it doesn't mention threads which increase the chance of a hangup immensely. :-)