# how to avoid "Not Responding"

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keep app responsive during long task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436524/keep-app-responsive-during-long-task)

how to avoid "Not Responding", when processing large query or long process looping?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never ever use `Application.ProcessMessages`, it opens up a can of worms.
Really.
Let me repeat: DO NOT USE `Application.ProcessMessages`.
[This is why](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=56704#56704): it requires all of your messaging to always be reentrant.
Your messaging, and more importantly messaging in libraries you use (the kind of which you cannot be sure it is reentrant).
Now, and in the future.
Even in cases you have not yet tested, or usage patterns you have not yet seen.

You should do multi-threading.
You really should.
It might take some time to get your synchronization right, but using somethine like a [backgroundworker](http://www.delphiarea.com/articles/backgroundworker-v1_1/) encapsulates most that in a neat way.

If you can't do multi-threading, then you can [cheat](http://blog.excastle.com/2005/08/15/telling-windows-were-not-really-not-responding/).
But you shouldn't cheat.

Cheating is about postponing your real solution.
Postponing costs more than doing it now.

It is all about [upstream decisions and downstream costs](http://www.stevemcconnell.com/articles/art08.htm).
Fixing a bad decision later is way more expensive than taking the right decision now, and investing a bit of time to do it right.

**Edit:**

The only exception for using a secondary message loop is when showing modal forms or dialogs. There the secondary message loop has a confined reach of those messages because of the modality.

**Edit 2:**

The modality results in all other forms to be automatically disabled; timers and other non UI messages however are still being processed, so re-entrancy can still occur.

--jeroen

Comment: This ranting against `Application.ProcessMessages` is a little tiresome. Running a secondary message loop presents only a problem if the code isn't reentrant, but that is a valuable property in itself. Simply moving code to worker threads may create the very same problems as `Application.ProcessMessages`, one *has to make sure* that it is impossible to re-enter any code path that isn't safe. There's no difference between needing to disable a button because the worker thread is still running, and having to do so because the called code contains `Application.ProcessMessages`.

Comment: @Jeroen I make a living off a program that calls `Application.ProcessMessages` without problems, so it can be done. But, yes, threads are better.

Comment: @mghie: the trick with putting your work in a thread is that only the things interacting with that thread need to be thread safe. You have influence over that. With `Application.ProcessMessages` all of your message processing needs to be thread safe, especially the bits you don't have influence over.

Comment: @Jeroen: Yes, I understand you, but I still think that the dangers of `Application.ProcessMessages` are vastly overstated. Yes, one needs to know what they're doing, but that seems a good idea in any case. And threads are no panacea, especially with thread-affinity of the GUI or database access components. GUI-heavy stuff with user interaction is best done in the GUI thread, otherwise program design will become overcomplicated for no benefit. If all you want to do is giving the user a chance to press "Cancel" then a secondary message loop is the right tool for the job.

Comment: @mghie: I agree that both can take quite some effort to get right. Having been bitten by the two myself, and the scars for threading were less than with `Application.ProcessMessages` because it was easier to shield the threading from side effects, and the message processing bit me because of code from others backfiring at me (there was a loophole where users could still perform actions). Maybe others have a different experience, but getting the messaging thing right was tough because it was much harder to contain.

Comment: Just to cast my vote against Application.ProcessMessages: I'm using FastReports, it's a nice reporting framework but the authors had the brilliant idea to call `Application.ProcessMessages` from the reporting engine. It's absolutely ugly: If for any reason the report takes more then a split second to show up, the user is free to press the `Print` button again. And following elevator best practices, they might press the button multiple times, just to be sure. Shielding against this takes lots of unnecessary work!

Comment: Jeroen : Please write a blog post on this!!!

Comment: @Jeroen Do you ever call `TForm.ShowModal`? If so then you are running a secondary message loop. I believe this concern over the use of secondary message loops to be bogus.

Comment: Modal dialogs is an exception in that there the secondary message loop has a confined reach of those messages. I'll add that to my answer. Maybe that covers the downvote my answer recently got.

Comment: @Jeroen I don't know what you mean about "confined reach". What about timers? And anyway, modality doesn't mean that re-entrancy does not occur.

Comment: confined in the sense that all your other forms are automatically disabled; timers and other non UI messages however are still being processed, so re-entrancy (that's where we Dutch would use an `ë` to avoid the `-`) can still occur.

Answer (score 4):

Execute it in separate thread. (see TThread class)

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective you have two choices(depending on HOW LONG the task(or loop) will take):

- use a thread as Alexander Malakhov mentioned;
- add Application.ProcessMessages(forces the application to draw UI and to respond to events, but it's not as good when the loop takes a lot of time -- use thread..) after each loop completion if you would like the application to respond, however I would recommend it only for -small amount of time- loops, for long intensive loops use threads.

Comment: No, no, no, NO! DON'T use Application.Process messages; it has way too many side effects (https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=56704#56704) and requires ALL message handling to always be reentrant. Not only your message handling. ALL message handling, everywhere in your app, now and in the future. DON'T!

Comment: +1 Yes Jeroen, but if he is a beginner, this will help him(hopefully) understand the real value of threads, if he is not a beginner then he already knows that, at any rate, you are right, however for his purposes it might do the trick.

Comment: That's why I suggested the backgroundworker in my answer. It makes multi-threading life a lot easier.